# Play wav sound from parameterized URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to play audio in my web page. For this I try to use a  method.

```
<embed src="success.wav" autostart=true loop=false>
```

But I have to make a server call for geting a wave file like

```
URL/play.php?file="success.wav"&log=353534543
```

which returns a success.wav file. I tried this one but not working

```
<embed src="URL/play.php?file=success.wav&log=353534543" autostart=true loop=false>
```

Any other good way to play a wav file in browser with this kind of parameterized URL. I dont want to use flash.

Each time a download window is opened not audio is playing.

Comment: You're not escaping success.wav, notice you end the quote before success and resume it after .wav... this is not correct, and will have an error

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

`<embed src="URL/play.php?file=success.wav&log=353534543" autostart=true loop=false>`

You don't need those extra quotes, they break the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in a project not long ago, requires JavaScript, it may be overkill for your implementation, but it's a good cross-browser compatible solution.

**SoundManager2:** http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

At the top of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var music=1;
soundManager.setup({
    html5Test: /^(probably|maybe)$/i,
    useHTML5Audio: true,
    onready: function() {

        music = soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'music',
            url: 'URL/play.php?file=success.wav&log=353535',
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

And then when you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
music.play();
</script>
```

Comment: Most modern browsers use HTML5 `<audio>`, but yes, Flash is required if HTML5 `<audio>` tag is not supported by the browser. The average user has one or the other I would think.